# replace part of the string in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas data frame in which I need to replace one part of the vale with another value

for Example. I have

```
HF - Antartica
HF - America
HF - Asia
```

out of which I'd like to replace ony the `HF -` part
thus the result would be

```
Hi Funny Antartica
Hi Funny America
Hi Funny Asia
```

I have tried `pd.replace()` but it doesnt work as I need only one part of the string replaced, rather than the entire string

Comment: can you show the dataframe declaration?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It seems you need [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
print (df)
              val
0  HF - Antartica
1    HF - America
2       HF - Asia

print (df.val.replace({'HF -':'Hi'}, regex=True))
0    Hi Antartica
1      Hi America
2         Hi Asia
Name: val, dtype: object
```

Similar solution with [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
print (df.val.str.replace('HF -', 'Hi'))
0    Hi Antartica
1      Hi America
2         Hi Asia
Name: val, dtype: object
```

Comment: +1 The `series.replace` solution did not make the replacement in my dataframe with either `regex=True` or with `regex=False`. I don't know why, but when I used `str.replace`, it worked

Comment: @mikey you probably forgot to use "inplace=True" at the end of your series.replace command

Comment: In case someone needs to replace across the df not series, try this: df.replace(regex=['HF -'], value='Hi Funny')

Comment: `str.replace(..., regex=True)` is significantly faster than `Series.replace(..., regex=True)`

Comment: Useful answer, wanted to do some replacement in a dataframe column for the following string '. St.'.  Had to  add the \ in other for the full stop to be escaped  ->> df.column_1.str.replace('\. St.', '').

Comment: the regex=True made the difference, otherwise a part of string was not replaced

Answer (score 18):

To add to @jezrael's answer, you need to include `regex=True` otherwise it would match directly. Also, here it replaces the values across all columns in the data frame. If you don't intend this, you could filter to a column and then replace. For replacing across all values in the data frame, try:

`df.replace('HF', 'Hi Funny', regex=True)`

You could also provide a list based patterns and replacement values. The complete set of options are provided in the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html).

So if the data frame is:

```
>df = pd.DataFrame({'Column': ['HF - Antartica', 'HF - America', 'HF - Asia']})
>df.replace('HF', 'Hi Funny', regex=True)
```

should print:

```
                 Column
0  Hi Funny - Antartica
1    Hi Funny - America
2       Hi Funny - Asia
```

Answer (score -2):

I would like to share one more  thing that is very much important, you can replace full stop with space ". " with "." normal full stop

```
df['label']=df.label.replace({"\. ": "."},regex=True)
```

Comment: @Samad I can take a point from your answer.  That is to replace  a full stop, it needs to be escaped when using regular expressions using ' \' .