# how to replace in pandas int values with a "," for thousands with an int without ','?

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a df thats big, and has int's and float's inside, some have bigger values over 1 thousand, and that gives error when using them as int

ex:
A           B         C
0      1,598    65.79       79
1      -300     46.90       90

[the format doesnt let me write the df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leUQh.png)

How can I replace the "," for this: ""?

Comment: If you want to replace all commas, then you can do: `'A B C 1,598 65.79 79 -300 46.90 90'.replace(',', '')`

The `replace(a, b)` string method in python replaces occurences of `a` with `b`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replace part of the string in pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42331992/replace-part-of-the-string-in-pandas-data-frame)

Comment: sorry ... it doesnt do the job for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df`

```
    A       B       C
0   1,598   65.79   79
1   -300    46.90   90
```

use following code:

```
df = df.astype('str').apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.str.replace(',', '')))
```

check data type of result

```
df.dtypes

A      int64
B    float64
C      int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: hi, is it possible to add something to filter when is or isnt a string? (I have columns that are strings )

Comment: how did you write the df to show it correctly?

Comment: `df[['A', 'B', 'C']] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].astype('str').apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.str.replace(',', '')))` if you want apply to only 'A', 'B', 'C' columns, use indexing

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are taking data from a CSV file, you can provide a converting function for the column.
Have a look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for pd.read_csv()

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

def convert_value(input_value):
    return input_value.replace("Dollars", "Pounds")

df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv", converters={"UNITS":convert_value})
```

^ Just something I wrote for a sample file, in your 'convert_value' function you would just do your own conversion (string to int presumably).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, its a json, do you know how the converters in read_json work?

Comment: sorry, this doesnt do the job for me